# How can i pass NULL value in ajax jquery call?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to handle null value when doing Ajax Call?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Login.aspx/SaveFacebookAutoSignUp",
            data: "{ 'Name':'" + rows[0].name + "', 'EmailId': '" + rows[0].email + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("You have successfully sign in.");

            }
        });
```

This is saving "null" value in my DB for EmailId when it is not fetch from other page?

I want to save "NULL" (DB default NULL allow) in DB when it is not having any value?

What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **undefined** instead of **null**, as in the following example:

```
data: {
  valueTrue : true,
  valueFalse: false,
  valueNull : undefined
}
```

Comment: is this still true in newer versions of jQuery? in my case it won't even pass that parameter in the request, it will only pass valueTrue and valueFalse in your example

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the value `null` *NOT* surrounded by quotes.

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "nullableValue": null
}
```

I'd suggest not composing your json string manually, create an object then use a function call to convert it to json. In some cases you can just pass the object to the `ajax` call.

Comment: you are right, but in this case when I have email value i.e abc@d.com, it is not call the function "SaveFacebookAutoSignUp" and not save in DB.

Comment: More over, if i do using PageMethod....... it is not calling when I have google OAuth on the same page.

Comment: PageMethods.SaveFacebookAutoSignUp(rows[0].name, rows[0].email, LoginSuccess);

Comment: this is the reason, i have use ajax jquery

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this in C# Coding Level . 
Just create parameter by using following method

```
public static SqlParameter GetSqlParameter(string StrParameterName,object ObjValue,SqlDbType Dbtype)
    {
        SqlParameter ObjParameter = new SqlParameter();




        ObjParameter.ParameterName = StrParameterName;

        if (ObjValue is DateTime)
            ObjParameter.IsNullable = (DateTime)ObjValue == new DateTime() ? true : false;
        else
            ObjParameter.IsNullable = ObjValue == null ? true : false;

        if (!ObjParameter.IsNullable)
            ObjParameter.Value = ObjValue;
        else
            ObjParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;

        ObjParameter.SqlDbType = Dbtype;

        return ObjParameter;

    }
```

Put this method in any of your Helper class and call it whenever you need .